# Unable to reference member of source code from markdown file with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Using Doxygen, I can't get code references to work from within markdown files. I've tried all sorts of combinations to no avail:

- `\ref myFunction`
- `myFunction()`
- `MyClass::myFunction`

They all result in something like `page.md:3: warning: unable to resolve reference to 'MyClass::myFunction' for \ref command`.

All of these generate links just fine when used in Doxygen comments in the code. I haven't found anyone else with this problem. Any ideas?

Doxygen version: 1.9.8

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? With a small complete example showing the problem it is not possible to tell what the problem might be, so at least the markdown file, the file(s) defining `myFunction` and the differences from the default doxygen settings (i.e. the result of  `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) incorporated in the question are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @albert for the suggestion to reduce it down. I discovered that documentation for members can refer directly to other members within the same namespace, but markdown pages need the fully-namespaced identifier to refer to a member. In the repository I'm working with all the code was put into its own namespace, so I had to do `theNamespace::MyClass::myFunction` for it to work.